# django update (soft delete) status instead of delete

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am developing an rest framework api project with django. The default create/update/get/delete works easily without any major coding.

All my models has a status_id field which denotes active and deleted. I only want to update the status to 'deleted' when someone try to delete a table row.
I wonder is there any way to update the status of a table row instead of deleting it. So that I can review the past data if something happened in future.

What code need to be added in views and serializers for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `ViewSet` the easiest way to override the default deletion behavior would be to override its `destroy` method.

```
class ExampleViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def destroy(self, request, pk=None):
        # Lookup record
        # Set deletion flag
        # Save record
```

You can find more information on `ViewSets` [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing).